# Use of Uber app and car services and liability

Tags: insurance

I use Uber app as a passenger. I investigated Uber site.

It appears that *passengers* are covered up to **$1mil** regardless of what insurance driver maintains outside of Uber.

- Is this correct?
- Is this in all states?
- Is this optional or mandatory for Uber drivers?

Comment: The Uber legal docs https://www.uber.com/legal/other/ answer all your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sort of seems to be true, [according to Uber](https://www.uber.com/us/en/drive/insurance/). Specifically, Uber covers driver liability (so it's about Uber and its relationship to drivers, not Uber and the customer: it covers the driver's liability). They maintain $1,000,000 third-party liability insurance and uninsured / underinsured motorist bodily injury. They provide insurance certificates within the US [here](https://www.uber.com/newsroom/certificates-insurance-u-s-ridesharing/), and this covers the 50 states plus DC and Puerto Rico. The state of Washington certificate is [here](https://ubernewsroomapi.10upcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/WA-COI-P1-3-Phys-Dam.pdf), and here is [Texas](https://ubernewsroomapi.10upcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/TX-COI-P1-3.pdf). These are informational summaries, not insurance policies, so the devil is in the actual contract, but it seems to match their online self-representation. The one point that may need to be clarified is that this covers up to $1M of total driver liability, not just passengers.

It's not clear whether an Uber driver can refuse such coverage purchased on his own behalf – you'd have to look at the contract between the driver and the company. Of course the driver has to have liability insurance anyway: Uber simply makes sure that happens, and increases coverage above the statutory minimum.

Comment: "Some people who drive with Uber are commercially licensed and insured for limousine, livery, black car, or private hire. Coverage for vehicle damage and liability arising from those trips is covered by their commercial automobile insurance."